# How to return a boolean from an angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a generic crud factory that is proving rather useful so far, the only problem is, when I go to use the service and check the result the value is not retaining the boolean true. I believe this is because javascript return acts on a per function basis, but I am not sure how to manuver the boolean out properly. Any ideas?

```
module.factory('crud', function ($http, API_CONFIG) {
    return {
        delete: function ($index, $scope, id, collection) {
            $http({
                url: API_CONFIG.url + collection + "/" + id,
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" }
            }).success(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $scope.countries.splice($index, 1);
                return true;
            }).error(function () {
                console.log("error");
            });
        },
        update: function ($index, $scope, id, collection) {
            console.log("update");
            console.log(id);
            console.log(collection);
        },
        create :function(model, collection) {
            $http.post(
                API_CONFIG.url + collection,
                JSON.stringify(model),
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
            ).success(function (data) {
                console.log("model sent");
                return true;
            }).error(function () {
                console.log("error");
            });;
        }
    };
});

module.run(function ($rootScope, crud) {
    $rootScope.appData = crud;
});
```

Then used like so in controller:

```
var result = $scope.appData.create(country, "collection");
if (result === true) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using return inside a callback function that is asynchronous. Therefore the code that is executed afterwards should also by asynchronous. Try passing an additional function to `create` that will be executed on success. For example:

```
create: function(model, collection, callback) {
  $http.post(...)
    .success(function(data) { callback(data, true); })
    .error(function(data) { callback(data, false); });
}
```

You can then use this like:

```
appData.create(model, collection, function(data, success) {
    if(success === true) {
          ...
    } else {
          ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise `return $http` on the factory and them do something like this:

```
$scope.appData.create(country, "collection").then(function() {
   // like a result = true;
}, function() {
   // like a result = false;
});
```

Comment: I did `return $http;` (and im certain it's getting hit) but I get an error: `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in reference to the first `.then` in the controller.

Comment: @user4612487 to make it working you should also follow the promise pattern of `.then` in service create function

Comment: @user4612487 would help if you post your controller content as well, you could be calling this method from inside another callback that doesn't return whats the factory methods do.